# Exit Program in AS400 cobol still continue to run

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I dont know why the succeeding section is still running after the Exit Program.

Here is my code:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                   
       PROGRAM-ID. PGM2.                                      
      /                                                           
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                      
       CONFIGURATION SECTION.                                     
       SOURCE-COMPUTER.                                IBM-AS400. 
       OBJECT-COMPUTER.                                IBM-AS400. 
      /                                                           
       DATA DIVISION.                                             
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                   
       01  WS-VARS                        PIC X(10).              
      /                                                           
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                        
       000-MAIN SECTION.                                          
      ******************                                          
       010-START.                                                 
      *                                                           
           INITIALIZE WS-VARS.                                    
      *                                                           
       090-EXIT.                                                  
           EXIT PROGRAM.                                          
      /                                                           
       200-WRITE-LINE SECTION.       
      ************************       
       210-START.                    
      *                              
           DISPLAY 'STILL RUNNING'.  
      *                              
       290-EXIT.                     
           EXIT.                     
      /
```

This program is being called in another program. After the Exit Program, I am expecting it to return to the program that calls it but it is still continuing to run. Please help me to understand why.

Edit: I found out that if the calling program is another COBOL program, it will exit the program as per my expectation. But it seems that if the calling program is a CLP, the EXIT PROGRAM does not exiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `EXIT PROGRAM` only leaves the program to the COBOL caller.

What you want to do (in nearly all cases) is to use `GOBACK` as it always leaves the run unit, no matter how it was invoked. If it was `CALL`ed from COBOL, it has the same effect as `EXIT PROGRAM`, otherwise as `STOP RUN`.

Answer (score 0):

The "EXIT PROGRAM" clause should be insert as unique statement in a paragraph.
Can you try this?

```
<..>
       010-START.
      *                                                           
           INITIALIZE WS-VARS.
      *
       090-EXIT.
      /

       100-START
           EXIT PROGRAM.
       190-EXIT.
      /

       200-WRITE-LINE SECTION.       
<..>
```

Or this:

```
<..>
       010-START.
      *                                                           
           INITIALIZE WS-VARS.
      *
       090-EXIT.
           EXIT.
      /

       200-WRITE-LINE SECTION.       
<..>
```

if it doesn't work, can you try to substitute "EXIT PROGRAM" clause with "GOBACK", always if your cobol version support this method:

```
 <..>
           010-START.
          *                                                           
               INITIALIZE WS-VARS.
               GOBACK.
          *
           090-EXIT.
          /

           200-WRITE-LINE SECTION. 
 <..>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `EXIT` statement should be in a paragraph alone according to COBOL85, but that doesn't apply to `EXIT PROGRAM`. If this is an issue, then you get a compile error, not a "not working program".
`GOBACK` is available on nearly all COBOL85 compilers as an extension (one exception is GCOS),. The [COBOL/400 Language Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rdfi/9.6.0?topic=cobol400-language-reference) also includes it.